# Unexpected Token for TSX scripts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, babel-jest

I'm attempting to test TSX component files using jest, from within a JSX test and am getting an output that indicates to me that the code itself is failing to transpile.

If I rename my test to *.test.jsx, the test will execute but the component script will fail to be parsed;

```
    SyntaxError: .../child/accessdoor.tsx: Unexpected token (50:16)

      48 |         const { displayFloor } = this.props;
      49 |         const upstairsDoorsTip = "Do you have any balcony doors or other access doors upstairs?";
    > 50 |         return (<>
         |                 ^
```

If I rename the test to *.test.tsx the test itself will fail at being parsed;

```
                const component = enzyme_1.shallow(<yourhome_1.EntranceExitDoorChoice {...emptyProps}/>);
                                                   ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Please note, I'm using a create-react-app bootstrapped projected and I'd *prefer* not to eject but i'm not apposed to it, if it's a necessity.

I've tried multiple configurations and extensions but not quite hit the sweet spot of a fully executed test. Using Webstorm's built in jest runner I have had the test execute and store a snapshot with output that I expect so I'm confident that the code itself passes.

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);

  const presets = [
    "react-app",
      "@babel/env",
    "@babel/react",
    "@babel/typescript"
  ];

  const plugins =  [
    "@babel/proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/proposal-object-rest-spread"
  ];

  return {
    presets,
    plugins
  };
};
```

jest.config.js

```
// For a detailed explanation regarding each configuration property, visit:
// https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

module.exports = {
    // Automatically clear mock calls and instances between every test
    // clearMocks: true,

    // Indicates whether the coverage information should be collected while executing the test
    collectCoverage: true,

    // The directory where Jest should output its coverage files
    coverageDirectory: "coverage",
    testEnvironment: "jsdom",

    preset: 'ts-jest',

    testPathIgnorePatterns: [
        "/node_modules/",
        "__tests__/setup/"
    ],

    moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.(jsx|js)$': 'babel-jest',
        "^.+\\.(tsx|ts)$": "ts-jest"
    },
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setupTests.ts'],

    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
    },

    testMatch: [
        '<rootDir>/src/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)',
        '<rootDir>/src/__tests__/**/*.ts?(x)'
    ],

    globals: {
        'ts-jest': {
            babel: true,
            tsConfig: "tsconfig.json"
        }
    }
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2017"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/"
  ]
}
```

Edit:

Changing

```
const component = shallow(<AccessDoorChoice {...emptyProps}/>);
```

to

```
const component = shallow(React.createElement(AccessDoorChoice, emptyProps));
```

Will cause the *test* to execute but the suite will fail in the component implementation, obviously the code base is quite large and i'm not up for replacing all the JSX!

Comment: I had a similar scenario but not quite exactly like this. I think my solution was to conf @babel/env, this is my conf:


```
module.exports = function(api){
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: [
        [
            "@babel/env",
            {
                targets: {
                    browsers: ["last 2 versions"],
                },
            },
        ],
        "@babel/preset-react",
        "@babel/preset-typescript",
        "@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop"
    ],
    plugins: [["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]],
  }   
};

```

Comment: Thanks for your help @rymdmaskin, unfortunately this one doesn't work for me :/

Comment: `jest.config.js -> globals.ts-jest.babel` wrong key, should be `babelConfig`.

Comment: But your trouble doesn't stop here man. You use `babel.config.js` not `.babelrc` so I guess `ts-jest` don't recognize it. I don't know the correct config, but you surely have quite some [docs](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/user/config/babelConfig) to read. Also check babel's doc on how to use options, I remember sth like `rootMode`

Comment: I'm sorry, but you config is quite messed up. Do you even use the typescript compiler to compile? If yes `@babel/typescript` preset isn't necessary, if no then you should just use `babel-jest` to keep align to your compile setup.